# Would an image sensor with photosites arranged irregularly to reduce aliasing be feasible?

Tags: aliasing, sensor

I’m guessing it’ll be more computationally complex considering the irregularly sampled image would have to be converted to a regularly sampled one and probably a different demosaicing algorithm would have to be used as well but is it something today’s image processors can’t handle ?? And what other issues could arise ??

Comment: Not exactly what you describe, but are you aware of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fujifilm_X-Trans_sensor

Comment: Feasible mathematically? Probably. Feasible in high-yield manufacturing? Questionable.

Comment: Irregular sampling wouldn't reduce aliasing - it would just change the nature of the signals that get aliased.

Comment: @TimWescott Could you please explain why it won’t reduce aliasing ?

Comment: Your question asks about feasibility, not about _whether_ an irregularly-spaced array would alias.  In short, however, if you assume an array of infinitesimal pixels, pointed at an object which is white, painted with black circles arranged such that they fill half of the objects surface yet are never seen by the pixels, then the resulting image will be purely white.  This is analogous to viewing a striped image where all of the white stripes happen to be captured by a grid of pixels.  I'm going to assert, without proof, that you could extend this to 100% fill factor with irregular pixels.